# Accessing members of a custom class list

Tags: c#, list

I have a class `Author.cs` as:

```
public class Author
{
   public Author()
   { }  

   public int AuthorID { get; set; }
   public string AuthorName { get; set; }
   public List<AuthorAttributes> Attributes { get; set; }  
   // ...member methods...
}
```

and a class `AuthorAttributes.cs` as:

```
public class AuthorAttributes  
{  
   public AuthorAttributes()  
   { }  

   public List<int> PaperID = new List<int>();     // public int PaperID;
   public List<int> CoAuthorID = new List<int>();  // public int CoAuthorID;
   public List<int> VenueID = new List<int>();     // public int VenueID;
   public int Year { get; set; } 
}
```

Each `Author` has `AuthorAttributes` e.g. for `AuthorID = 677` there are number of `PaperID`s, `CoAuthorID`s and `VenueID`s in a certain `Year`s as:

```
Author_ID | Author_Name | Paper_ID | CoAuthor_ID | Venue_ID | Year
------------------------------------------------------------------
677       | Nuno Vas    | 812229   | 901706      | 64309    | 2005  
677       | Nuno Vas    | 812486   | 901706      | 65182    | 2005  
677       | Nuno Vas    | 818273   | 901706      | 185787   | 2005  
677       | Nuno Vas    | 975105   | 901706      | 113930   | 2007  
677       | Nuno Vas    | 975105   | 1695352     | 113930   | 2007  
...       | ...         | ...      | ...         | ...      | ...
```

I want to store this data in C# variables as `Author_ID` and `Author_Name` in class `Author` and rest of the fields in class `AuthorAttributes` and then having a list of `AuthorAttributes` attached with each `Author_ID` in class `Author.cs` as shown above.

When I read data from SQL Server database, I have to read rows one by one that's why I declared properties of class `AuthorAttributes` as `int` whereas actually each `Author` will have a list of `Papers`, `CoAuthors` and `Venues` in certain `Years`.

**EDIT**

I want as I declare the object of class `Author.cs` e.g.

```
Author author = new Author();
```

then the object `author` should contain as follows:
`Author_ID` in `AuthorID`
`Author_Name` in `AuthorName`
`Paper_ID` in `Attributes`
`CoAuthor_ID` in `Attributes`
`Venue_ID` in `Attributes`
`Year` in `Attributes`

**Sample Code for Database Reading**

```
while (myReader_1.Read())
{
   int authorID = myReader_1.GetInt32(0);
   Author author = eAthors.FirstOrDefault(_a => _a._AuthorID == _authorID);
   if (author == null)
   {
      author = new Author
                            {
                                AuthorID = authorID,
                                AuthorName = myReader_1.GetString(1),
                                Attributes = new List<AuthorAttributes>()
                            };
     eAuthors.Add(author);
    }  
    author.Attributes.Add(new AuthorAttributes  
                                               {
                                                 PaperID = new List<int>() { myReader_1.GetInt32(2) },
                                                 CoAuthorID = new List<int>() { myReader_1.GetInt32(3) }, 
                                                 VenueID = new List<int>() { myReader_1.GetInt32(4) },
                                                 Year = myReader_1.GetInt32(5),
                                               }
                           );
}
```

It looks like `Attributes` is a list and make sense, but each individual attribute itself is also a list as `Paper_ID`s, `CoAuthor_ID`s and `Venue_ID`s are more than one for `Author_ID = 677` in a certain `Year`

How to define properties of class `AuthorAttributes` as `int` **OR** `List<int>` ?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you want to achieve. Maybe show the end result you want to have, it would make the situation clearer

Comment: AuthorAttributes Table must include the Author_id so there is a link between the author and his attributes.

Comment: @jdweng we are having `List<AuthorAttributes>` in the `Author.cs` class, will it not be the link?

Comment: No, its a thesis project

Comment: @NamelessOne The base of question is: by declaring object of class `Author.cs`, getting *all of data* in single object

Comment: You classes properties in c# and your datatable columns in SQL need to have bindings that is one to one.  It would be easier if the tables in the SQL Database had the same properties as your classes.

Comment: @jdweng The data I have shown is one of SQL table I have, and so are the classes I tried to design

Comment: @jdweng can you guide that how to add values in `AuthorID`, `AuthorName` and `Attributes` (properties of class `Author.cs`) using `SqlDataReader`?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I think now its clear what I want to achieve...is it so?

Comment: Does following article help? : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj943772.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, each individual attribute itself is a list, so you should define them as list of int, or even list of strings if some IDs contains characters.
I guess the sample of code for Database Reading should look more like:

```
    while (myReader_1.Read())
    {
       int authorID = myReader_1.GetInt32(0);
       Author author = eAthors.FirstOrDefault(_a => _a._AuthorID == _authorID);
       if (author == null)
       {
          author = new Author
                                {
                                    AuthorID = authorID,
                                    AuthorName = myReader_1.GetString(1),
                                    Attributes = new List<AuthorAttributes>()
                                };

var attribute = new AuthorAttributes()
{
PaperID = new List<int>(),
CoAuthorID = new List<int>(),
VenueID = new List<int>()
};

attribute.PaperID.Add(myReader_1.GetInt32(2));
attribute.CoAuthorID.Add(myReader_1.GetInt32(3));
attribute.VenueID.Add(myReader_1.GetInt32(4));
attribute.Year = myReader_1.GetInt32(5);

author.Attributes.Add(attribute);



eAuthors.Add(author);
}
}
```

Comment: but when I read values from database, then how to read in Lists if I declare these properties as Lists? whereas the sample code which I have shown is creating a new list for each attribute every time loop iterates which is not desired :(

Comment: You should instantiate lists before you read from database, then you should call .add on each property with the IDs fom database

Comment: Unable to access .add method on each property even after initializing e.g. `_PaperID` in class `AuthorAttributes`

Comment: Why not, it should work just like in your example where you call Attributes.Add. Have you made the properties lists?

Comment: Yeah as you can see in `AuthorAttributes.cs` class, now I have declared all attributes as Lists of int

Comment: But it is not allowing me to access .Add method for `List<int> PaperID` inside `author.Attributes.Add(new AuthorAttributes { PaperID.Add(); // Here unable to use .Add method } `

Comment: I have provided all of the code above, please suggest the suitable code EDIT

Comment: Sorry, now I have seen the rest of the comments. It will only let you access it otside the constructor call, I mean outside of the initialization list. Try to do it in separate statements and it will work

Comment: But the issue is I can't access the property i.e. `PaperID` outside the statement `author.Attributes.Add (new AuthorAttributes { PaperID }`

Comment: If you please have a look at **sample code for database reading** above, you may get some idea what I'm asking about

Comment: Let me edit my answer so it will look close to what I think will be the solution

Comment: I have edited it, this way you can add multiple IDs to the same author attributes. It should be modified not to overrite the older IDs by making new list everytime, and maybe should check for null before and only if the list is null then make a new one

Comment: I tried your suggested code but `author.PaperID.....` not accessible here as`author.Attributes` is accessible

Comment: sorry, I should have written athor.Attributes.PaperID, my fault

Comment: I have tried author.Attributes.PaperID also, but its also inaccessible as Attributes is a list so only build in methods for a list are accessible

Comment: Again, you are right, the attribute should be hold as local variable before being added to list

Comment: So how to reach at list PaperID, how to access it here

Comment: It looks fine as I haven't got any code editor error hope it should work that not to create a new list of PaperID and so on at each loop iteration

Comment: Can I write eAuthors.Add(author) twice ? One at end of if(author == null) condition and one at the end of while () ?

Comment: Look careful, it's only eauthor.Add(author) once, at the end of the while block

Comment: But I have made a mistake with one of the curly braces, the one in if should be at the end of the while too.

Comment: Its mean the one (eAuthors.Add(author)) I already had after if(author == null) condition should be removed ?

Comment: It should be just as in the code I posted, once, if it's twice then it should be removed, as you want to add the author with all the properties set. Please mark also as answer if it was what you were looking for

Comment: Fine, and why not I'll surely mark, just having an execution of code

Comment: Thank you very much, I was glad to help you!

Comment: One more off the topic question, what it means if we declare a property e.g. `List<int> PaperID` in a class and then have a method i.e. `List<int> GetPaperID()` that simply return that `PaperID`?

Comment: I don't understand the question properly. If you have a property int PaperID, then you can access it directly, and it will not be necessary to create a method GetPaperID()

Comment: I mean if I want to access all PaperIDs for a specific author, then how?

Comment: Well in this case you will need to know which of the attributes from the list of attributes it interest you, you can do something like author. Attributes[0].PaperID, and you will get all the paperIDs from the first of the attributes list, but I guess in this case you need only one item of the class Attribute in the class Author, not a list

Comment: I executed the code, it works fine for single iteration, but when it comes the 2nd iteration, the condition if(author == null) becomes false and it simply exits all if block, then next iteration same then next same and same so on....

Comment: yes, because you already have one athor in your eAthors. I guess there you should not use FirstOrDefault, because it will return always the very first author added, which is the default one. I guess you should use First instead of FirstOrDefault, or a method like this

Comment: Then do the author and Attributes have connection, mean authorID can distinguish (pickup) between its attributes from the list Attributes?

Comment: In this case the Attributes list will have only one element always

Comment: I think if(author == null) condition suits here, because as I removed that condition and each time a separate list of each of 3 attributes is being generated for same authorID  = 677 as you can see the data provided in the question

Comment: Also if you use First instead of FirstOrDefault I guess, with the if condition, the result should be the same

Comment: As long as Author_ID = 677 continues, the list `eAuthors` should contain a Count = 1, but here it is updating Count value with each row reading

Comment: Okay, I hope everything works well now, I guess it should

Comment: I'm sending you the image, what happening here then you might get the idea

Comment: Can we have a chat so that I can send you the image ?

Comment: I am not so good at database design, maybe you should open a separate question for this, and do not forget to mark this answer. I am stil a begginer, but it was challenging to help you!

Comment: Still I want to see you the image, may be you can click it better

Comment: I will try to look at it, but I can't promise anything. Can you update it on your question? I don't have the repputation to open a chat

Comment: I see, so which is the problem?

Comment: Read text for Image 1 and Image 2

Comment: I guess AuthorAttributes should be changed to a single object, instead a list. This may help, but I am not sure

Comment: The reason AuthorAttributes is defined as list is that each Author will have a list of Attributes though its limited to only 3 attributes (Paper, CoAuthor, Venue) for each author

Comment: yes, but you don't need the AuthorAttributes as a list since the Properties of AuthorAttributes are lists

Comment: What about text in Image 2 i.e. `eAuthors` should have `Count = 1` whereas its showing 3 and all of Attributes should have `Count = 3` because of 3rd iteration but all are showing `Count = 1` its mean each time a new List is being generated for each of Attribute ?

Comment: yes, this is happening there, that's why i say you may need to use First method instead of FirstOrDefault, keep the if condition, and convert AuthorAttributes from list to a single object. But this should not give you the behavior you want to reach, that is why I suggest to open another question. I may go to sleep now, do not forget to mark as answer, if I was helpful to you. It was nice to work with you!

Comment: Listen if we add a condition just like we added for author i.e. if (author == null) can't we have a condition for each Attribute so that it shouldn't create a new list each time for a single Author_ID i.e. 677 and so on...?

Comment: I'll vote you up also, nice co-operator you are, what time at yours? Its 2 AM at ours by the way

Comment: Yes, this is a good idea, you can try it. and add them to the existing attributes.  And the condition shoud be AuthorAttributes!=null

Comment: Yeah if we are able to limit `eAuthors` Count = 1 and extend Attriubtes Count = 3 after 3 iterations, that's all what we want here

Comment: But the heck is: I'll have to narrate the whole tale right from the start to start a new question on this issue :( anyhow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114438/discussion-between-taufel-and-mejustandrew).

Comment: I guess so, but until then I hope I helped you, thank you for the answer mark, and very much luck Iwish to you!